# show progressbar while data is loading Knockoutjs

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, progress-bar

I need some help in integrating a loading progress bar of JqueryUI to loading of data from a Observable array of KO. I have created some JsFiddles

```
fiddle for KnockOut : http://jsfiddle.net/neodescorpio/HksCA/

fiddle for JqueryUI Progress bar : http://jsfiddle.net/neodescorpio/NAs3V/
```

I need to combine both of these so that on loading of knock out a progress bar with percentage is shown and disappears after data is loaded 100%. If any other progressbar is used im okay with it. i just want a progress to be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a custom binding to manipulate the jQuery progress bar from knockout bindings.  For example something like that (very contrived example):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.progress = {
   init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      $(element).progressbar({
         value: 0
      });
   },
   update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
      var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
      $(element).progressbar("value", parseFloat(val));
   }
};
```

Now you can create a progress bar from a div and command it through an observable value (which should return a number, or a string representing a number, ranging from 1 to 100), by using the *progress* binding - e.g.:

```
<div data-bind="progress: percentComplete"></div>
```

I update your fiddle to show an example: http://jsfiddle.net/HksCA/2/

Comment: while i was working i did this

<div id ="progress_bar" class="loading_bar"> Loading Data</div>

function showProgress(level, n) {
   var divWidth = (((level + 1) / n) * 100) + "%";
   var progressDiv = document.getElementById("progress_bar");
   
   progressDiv.style.width = divWidth;
   progressDiv.innerText = divWidth + " Completed";

   if ((level + 1) == n) {
    jQuery(progressDiv).slideUp('slow');
   }
  }

Problem was that the progressbar only shows when all the data is loaded in the tbody.it should progress stepwiese on loading of each record.