# Knockout progressbar getting data from c# controller

Tags: c#, mvvm, knockout.js

I have an application that was built on MVVM pattern using Knockout.

Each ViewModel is getting its data from C# controller.
The controller calls a Manager class on the Business Logic layer.
How do I update a progress bar on the client from the controller?
I have a long operation that will be done on the Business Logic layer (involving database).

Whats the best practice for this problem?
Can someone give an example?

Comment: here is an example if that's what you are looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161526/show-progressbar-while-data-is-loading-knockoutjs

Comment: Thanks but i more interested in the mechanism to return progress by the c# controller.